# Laravel. Keep eloquent relationship after join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

suddenly i faced problem which I can't solve by myself. I wrote query which returns me some data:

```
$users = User::whereIn('users.status', array(2,3))
    ->leftJoin('firsts', 'firsts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->leftJoin('seconds', 'seconds.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->leftJoin('thirds', 'thirds.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->leftJoin('offers', 'offers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->where('users.status', '=', '2');
        $query->where('firsts.status', '=', 'approved');
        $query->where('seconds.status', '=', 'approved');
        $query->where('offers.user_id', '=', 'approved');
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query){
        $query->where('users.status', '=', '3');
        $query->where('users.stripe_active', '=', '1');
        $query->where('firsts.status', '=', 'approved');
        $query->where('seconds.status', '=', 'approved');
        $query->where('thirds.status', '=', 'approved');
        $query->where('offers.status', '=', 'approved');
    })
    ->get();
```

I were expecting simple object as a return from query. At the moment I have one proper record in my users table, but this query returns me that object 6 times, and I can't understand why.
 Results I'm expect:

```
Collection {#353 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => User {#354 ▼
      #dates: array:2 [▶]
      #table: "users"
      #fillable: array:3 [▶]
      #hidden: array:2 [▶]
      +admin: "eval.butkus@gmail.com"
      +admin2: "Evaldas"
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:31 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "username" => "evaldas"
        "password" => "$2y$10$ARTGHBTqIl/X6UsblylF5ugMPFlASwDKUEVbS5Nh3TjtycGG/NU7."
        "email" => "eval.butkus@gmail.com"
        "remember_token" => "A42ezMckkvjCLrpj4jxyHf2iSQWp3iAGfzGoTqMygDimFSzXNx6FW42qCOhP"
        "name" => ""
        "subscribe" => 0
        "profile_picture" => "VNlQxOlCbXkCGEQ6ZdFS1pbK2tixhsmmhQPhLNLMBRKqDzXegWbqQiJOsplMADKg.jpg"
        "about_you" => ""
        "writing_service" => 0
        "f_card" => 0
        "logo" => ""
        "website" => ""
        "youtube" => ""
        "status" => 3
        "code" => ""
        "active" => 1
        "address" => ""
        "phone" => ""
        "news" => 0
        "terms" => 1
        "radius" => 0
        "created_at" => "2015-07-13 10:26:47"
        "updated_at" => "2015-07-15 10:25:30"
        "stripe_active" => 1
        "stripe_id" => "cus_6c0xE8OxR7fdXJ"
        "stripe_subscription" => "sub_6c0x4RzEoBplCb"
        "stripe_plan" => "small"
        "last_four" => "4242"
        "trial_ends_at" => null
        "subscription_ends_at" => null
      ]
      #original: array:31 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
    }
  ]
}
```

Results i get:

```
Collection {#364 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    0 => User {#365 ▼
      #dates: array:2 [▶]
      #table: "users"
      #fillable: array:3 [▶]
      #hidden: array:2 [▶]
      +admin: "eval.butkus@gmail.com"
      +admin2: "Evaldas"
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:53 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "username" => "evaldas"
        "password" => "$2y$10$ARTGHBTqIl/X6UsblylF5ugMPFlASwDKUEVbS5Nh3TjtycGG/NU7."
        "email" => "sadsad"
        "remember_token" => "A42ezMckkvjCLrpj4jxyHf2iSQWp3iAGfzGoTqMygDimFSzXNx6FW42qCOhP"
        "name" => "sadsa"
        "subscribe" => 0
        "profile_picture" => "VNlQxOlCbXkCGEQ6ZdFS1pbK2tixhsmmhQPhLNLMBRKqDzXegWbqQiJOsplMADKg.jpg"
        "about_you" => ""
        "writing_service" => 0
        "f_card" => 0
        "logo" => ""
        "website" => "das"
        "youtube" => ""
        "status" => "approved"
        "code" => ""
        "active" => 1
        "address" => "asfas"
        "phone" => "dasd"
        "news" => 0
        "terms" => 1
        "radius" => 0
        "created_at" => "2015-07-15 07:31:37"
        "updated_at" => "2015-07-15 07:44:31"
        "stripe_active" => 1
        "stripe_id" => "cus_6c0xE8OxR7fdXJ"
        "stripe_subscription" => "sub_6c0x4RzEoBplCb"
        "stripe_plan" => "small"
        "last_four" => "4242"
        "trial_ends_at" => null
        "subscription_ends_at" => null
        "country" => "Highland"
        "mobile" => "asd"
        "descripsion" => "Ddescription"
        "landline" => "asdas"
        "company_name" => "das"
        "facebook" => "dsad"
        "twitter" => "sadsa"
        "linkedln" => "dsadasd"
        "company_number" => "sad"
        "google" => "sadasd"
        "vat" => "asdsad"
        "experience" => ""
        "privacy" => 0
        "user_id" => 1
        "post_code" => "AB115QN"
        "latitude" => "57.14270109"
        "longitude" => "-2.093014619"
        "identify" => "grEa6JEaj6P0I7Zc3ZCq5CADojzApSJZ.jpg"
        "bill" => "N8WKjRlSttsHNt1crrNdwxG7uqWEg5GB.jpg"
        "comment" => "asdsad"
        "image" => "7dmURWxbzO4pinqbek0yzdIKqEyZrjOD.jpg"
        "title" => "new offer"
      ]
      #original: array:53 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
    }
    1 => User {#366 ▶}
    2 => User {#367 ▶}
    3 => User {#368 ▶}
    4 => User {#369 ▶}
    5 => User {#370 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Could any explain how did i lose all the relationships between tables and how can I avoid it? Since structure of result changed, I can't use loops, relationships and etc. Thanks!.

Comment: Are all 6 users the same users?

Comment: Yes it's. I just tried to echo all the user_id's. All are the same.

Comment: Then one of the joined tables must have more than one record for given user. That's why I asked about it in the previious question, but then there was no Offers table linked to the user.

Comment: If there are multiple offers for a single user and you have "offers" relation defined in your User model, remove the join and do User::with('offers')->whereIn .... You should get one user and you'll be able to access offers by $user->offers

Comment: Now it's making more sense. My thirds table also have few records (hasMany) for one user, but I can identify status just by first record of the users.thirds. How should i handle it?

Comment: At the end of my object I can see `"offer":[]`. However, I still can't loop `$user->offer`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83324/discussion-between-jedrzej-kurylo-and-evaldas-butkus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If im reading this right, you just want to

```
(delete join onto orders)...->groupBy('users.id')->get();
```

That will return you one user matching the conditions.

You can achieve this with 2 queries, first group by on users (don't join orders), then do a second query for the orders. What else to join would depend on which tables you are using to filter users by vs which tables you are using to add data to orders with. 
Put data to add to orders in the second query, stuff your using to filter users in the first. You could also try a subquery but that isn't supported well in eloquent.

Also your whereIn is completely pointless, as you are already testing for where user status is 2 or 3.

Edited for a little more clarity,I was a little hasty. Originally thought that the poster wanted one row back - which wasn't the case.

Comment: Notice that status 3 have more conditions. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @EvaldasButkus I don't understand your comment. Did you try this to see the results?

Comment: Yes i tried, and it picks right records, but the problem is that object returned isin't proper to use for display.